# Importantion "uses" Management

Tags: delphi

I need to decrease the size of my executable, and often some "unnecessary" `uses` occupy to certain size in my executable.

For example:
   `Unit1` connects to `Unit2`, but the two units have the import "`System.SysUtils`".

Then "`System.SysUtils`" is being imported twice, and we assume that the size of this unit is `200KB`. Since I have two imports, would the total size be `400KB`?
*As they often happen in java.*
Or can I make multiple imports with unit "System.SysUtils" without changing the size of my executable?

Comment: No, System.SysUtils will only be included once. And it is indeed pretty big, although the size of the .dcu is unimportant. The linker can easily remove unused functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter how many times you have a unit "used". As long as it's being used anywhere, it will be compiled once. Otherwise, it won't.

The only time multiple compilations are made are when you have different compiler configurations (Debug/Release, Win32/Win64, etc.) (which would output different files anyway), or different projects altogether.

---

If you wish to decrease the size of your executable, find units which are used but not actually used at all. This can be tricky, considering many units you use are already using them. Clean them up the best you can. There are many other ways to decrease the size of your output file(s).

Comment: Or you use generics.

Answer (score 0):

Use ICARUS from http://www.peganza.com/download.html
It'll analyze the uses list and which units are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a toolset available for free: CnPackIDE Wizards that you can download from http://www.cnpack.org/
I deactivate most of them but I like the "Uses Cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

It won't be included multiple times, so the size will still be 200kB. You can make multiple imports